# Stem function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a discrete convolution:

```
n = 0:25;
x = 2 * (heaviside(n+2)-heaviside(n-12));
h = 0.9.^n .* (heaviside(n-2)-heaviside(n-13));
y = conv(x, h);
stem(n, y)
```

But I get a problem because the length of *n* is 26 and the length of *y* is 51, but I want to show the plot the convolution from *n = 0* to *n = 25*. How can I modify this code to obtain such result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the [documentation to the `conv` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html), you'll learn that it has a 3rd argument: a string that tells you how large the output should be.

```
y = conv(x, h, 'same');
```

will create a `y` that is the same size as `x` (and hence `n`).

Answer (score 2):

Without deeper knowledge of convolutions or such:

If you are just trying to get the vectors to be similar in size, skip elements of the vector like so:

```
stem(n, y(1:2:end)) % Take every other element of y
```

This at least produces some curve with discrete points.

Alternatively, make the `n` twice as long:

```
stem(0:.5:25, y) % Double the amount of elements previously in n
```